# ¿Porqué iframe se comporta de la siguiente manera?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Muy buenas, tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function func(){
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.background="blue";
        p.style.width= "50px";
        p.style.height= "50px";
        document.getElementById('contenido').contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(p);
        p.style.position = 'absolute';
            p.style.zIndex= 1000;
            function mo(pageX, pageY){
            p.style.left = pageX - p.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            p.style.top = pageY - p.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            }
            //mo(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            function mov(event){
                mo(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            }
            p.addEventListener('mousemove', mov);
            p.onmouseup = function(){
                p.removeEventListener('mousemove', mov);
            }
    }
```

```css
iframe{
            background: red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 0;
        }
```

```html
<iframe id="contenido">
          <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
              <p>Hola</p>
          </body>
          </html>
      </iframe>
    <button onclick="func()">Pulsame</button>
```

El problema es que si yo muevo el cuadrado azul hacia el final de abajo (o a la derecha) del iframe el cuadrado no se corta sino que baja un poco más a pesar de tener la propiedad overflow:hidden y se crea más espacio para el iframe, me gustaría saber porque se crea ese "espacio"(se alarga el iframe) y como puedo hacer que no se alargue.

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Por cierto si no me explico bien díganmelo.

Comment: yo no veo ningún cuadro azul solo aparece el rojo que supongo que el de fondo

Comment: al clicar el botón de "púlsame" debe crearse un cuadrado azul dentro del iframe. Aca en strack overflow no funciona con este editor, pero si lo pruebas en otro funcionara. Por ejemplo, [enlace al editor de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_default) , acá puedes borrar el código y escribir el mío y veras a lo que me refiero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estás asignando el overflow del iframe, pero en realidad el overflow que debes definir es el del body del elemento iframe. Prueba a modificar tu función de esta menera

```
function func(){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.style.background="blue";
    p.style.width= "50px";
    p.style.height= "50px";
    document.getElementById('contenido').contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById('contenido').contentWindow.document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // <== AÑADE ESTA LINEA
    p.style.position = 'absolute';
        p.style.zIndex= 1000;
        function mo(pageX, pageY){
        p.style.left = pageX - p.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
        p.style.top = pageY - p.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
        }
        //mo(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        function mov(event){
            mo(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        }
        p.addEventListener('mousemove', mov);
        p.onmouseup = function(){
            p.removeEventListener('mousemove', mov);
        }
}
```